# Keyboard closes immediately in modalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, dart

When I tap on a `TextField` or `FormTextField` inside a `modalBottomSheet` the keyboard closes immediately and shows this error

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15275): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15275): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15275): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

this is basically the code

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    enableDrag: true,
    builder: (context) {
        return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
               vertical: 32,
               horizontal: 16,
            ),
            child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                        children: [
                            Text(...),
                            FormTextField(
                                controller: _phonenumberController,
                                enabled: true,
                                focusNode: _focusNode,
                                textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                            ),
                            MaterialButton(...),
                        ],
                    ),
                    
                ),
            );
    },
);
```

I've tried to change it to `TextField`, I can't type unless `autofocus` is true but i don't want the keyboard to be always showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, all I did is change the `FormTextField`s to `TextField` and removed the `Form`,

This works for any one that has the same problem, but you'll not be able to validate the Field.